# When to tick "copy items into destination's group folder (if needed)"

Tags: xcode, organization

Whenever I am adding some files to my project by dragging and dropping in Xcode, a popup message is shown "Copy items into destination's group folder (if needed)".

I noticed that when we are using most of the third party library's we DON'T tick the checkbox and instead specify the library path in "Header Search Path/Library search Path". But for smaller resource files like images, we tick the checkbox.

Which specific scenarios do I have to tick and what difference will it make?

Answer (score 15):

It all depends on how you want to organize you project. It's far more common to store 3rd party frameworks somewhere on your machine that is independent of any project that may use that framework, thus allowing multiple projects to reference the same shared framework project from a standard directory. In that case, you don't want the 3rd party framework copied into your own project, and so you don't check that box.

Images and other resource files are typically owned on a project-by-project basis, so it makes the most sense to store those in the directory of the project itself. To pull that off, you check that box to make sure a copy is made in the project's directory if one doesn't already exist.

Neither of those rules are absolute, you could copy an entire framework into your project's directory if you want, and you could reference media assets from some standard location. It's all up to you to implement good project organization.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, your project is saved to a project folder. If you drag stuff from outside the folder into your project without copying, only references to the added files are stored. You will have to be careful not to delete them, or your project will break.

Also, if you are using version control, such as the built-in git, files not in the main folder will not get added to your version tree.

I got into the habit of copying everything I need into the main folder and then drag-add without copying. This is working well for me and has so far avoided any errors.